# Any REAL wireless webcams, that can be carried around and stream live in house?

Tags: video-camera, television, ip-camera, webcam

The short version:

**Can anyone recommend a webcam that I can carry around the house - totally unwired?** I guess it should be wifi, battery-charged, and if there are both mic and speakers it would be great. If it has fisheye lens it would be totally perfect. :)

Long version:

Ok, this might sound really silly. But a family member is totally scared of being alone, I can't even walk into the other room when I'm there, then she will start calling. So I was thinking of mounting my GoPro on a helmet and let her see me on a monitor in her room. However there is a delay with the GoPro camera (Silver 3+), which ruins the whole idea.

So my question is if there is a *real* wireless camera that I somehow can mount to a helmet, and stream via wifi to a computer and on to the monitor/TV via hdmi.

I have seen **Logitech Broadcaster Wi-Fi Webcam**, but it's a few years old, there gotta be newer and cheaper cameras? :-)

ANY ideas will help me, thanks! <3

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options available to you, depending on how much comfort you want to have vs. how much money you want to spend.

**1. There are a few do-it-yourself solutions as suggested by @filo**

You can use a Raspberry Pi + Camera + USB Battery pack to setup something, but it requires some effort and it's not going to be the most easy-to-use option.

**2. There are plenty of USB WiFi cameras available that would be suitable.**

Same as with the former option, just add a large battery pack and you have a mobile solution. (Nest Cam / Dropcam Example: http://www.instructables.com/id/Dropcam-Unplugged/) The clear advantage is less trouble setting it all up, but it's still not the most user-friendly, if you really want to carry it around.

**3. Build-in battery WiFi Cameras:**

- Logitech Circle http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/circle
- Netgear Arlo https://www.arlo.com/en-us/

These products have a build in Battery and are made to be used without any wires (until you have to recharge them).

You can read a comparative review on some of these options here:
http://arijaycomet.com/2016/01/23/comparison-netgear-arlo-q-vs-nest-cam-vs-logi-circle-vs-samsung-smarthd-vs-d-link-dcs-2630l/

**[ALTERNATIVE ANSWER]**

If your sole use case is for that family member to see you - I don't understand why you would want to carry the camera around on your helmet in the first place?

I think it would make more sense to either just install a few simple WiFi camera (e.g. Nest Cam) around the house and have her look at those on a tablet. They will show where you are and even give her security, when you are not there.

Alternatively, any **smartphone** you may already own, can do exactly what you want. Just start a Skype / FaceTime / Hangout call and carry your phone around. Assuming you already own a smartphone - it would be the no-cost option. (Well, you need a viewing tablet / computer for her, but you need that in any case.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a cheap tablet or smartphone with a streaming app?

You could also use a BananaPi with extra batteries, camera module and USB WiFi stick (or BananaPro with built-in WiFi). [Batteries require some simple soldering](http://lb9mg.no/2015/06/28/banana-pi-on-battery-power/).

Comment: The phone seems the sensible option here. Especially if she's carrying it around, and he wants low latency